# How to handle Javascript click by using selenium Webdriver?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

Am using Selenium Webdiver. My test-case is.

1. Login to site.
2. click on Notifications link.

am facing issue while clicking on notification link, having the HTML code as follows :-

```
<ul class="rghtSec fr menu logged"><li><a href="javascript:;">
  <div class="topIcon notify"><span>&nbsp;</span></div>
  <div class="mTxt">Notifications<span id="rJobCntr" class="rJobCntr"></span></div></a>
  <div class="subMenu recommendTT">
    <ul>
      <li><a target="_blank" class="blob" id="blobId" href="http://jobsearch.naukri.com/notifications">
Fetching jobs you may apply for</a></li>
    </ul>
```

I have tried by following 5 different ways:

```
/*1*/ driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='mTxt']")).click();

/*2*/ driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='topIcon notify']")).click();

/*3*/ driver.findElement(By.linkText("Notifications")).click();

/*4*/ driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pNotifyCont dspN']")).click();

/*5*/ Actions mouse=new Actions(driver);
   WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='pNotifyCont dspN']"));
   mouse.moveToElement(element).click().build().perform();
```

`Error : 
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@class='mTxt']"}
Command duration or timeout: 7.56 seconds`

But none of these ways are resolving the problem :(, Can anyone please help me to solve this?

Comment: Is there a possibility that your Link is in an iframe?

Comment: han.. but.. sorry.. its not in iframe / frameset. so i can't use that.

Comment: Please try driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a//div[@class='mTxt']")).click();

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your `xpath` expression as

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Notifications')]")).click();
```

The `Notifications` is in `div` tag.

If you want to select the element under this `Notifications` link, you can by following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Notifications')]/following::a[1]")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly click on the link based on the value of `href` attribute:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='notifications']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href=\"http://jobsearch.naukri.com/notifications\"]")).click();
```